# Excel 2016: Using Ribbon XML to add the Analysis Group to a Custom Tab for Windows and Mac

Tags: excel, xml, ribbon, ribbonx

I am putting the finishing touches on a customized tab I have added to the Excel 2016 Ribbon using XML with one final issue that I can't seem to get past: I cannot seem to find the idMso attribute for the Analysis group usually found in the Data tab. For ease of use for the intended users, I would like to add the Analysis group to my customized tab too. A few questions around this issue:

1) What is the idMso attribute for the Analysis group so I can add it to my custom tab?

2) Is it possible to use XML code to insure that the Data Analysis Tookpak is ALWAYS added to my custom Analysis group? If so, can someone suggest code to do this?

3) Right now, I am developing this code to run on Excel 2016 for Windows. Eventually, however, I want to incorporate this code in an Add-in for both Windows and Mac users. Will this XML code work for both Excel 2016 for Windows and Mac? If not, is it possible to use conditional logic in XML and have the code test whether the OS is Windows or Mac and then run the appropriate XML code to add the intended custom buttons and standard Excel groups to my customized tab?

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

The way I figured this out was to search for the file name `FUNCRES.XLAM` referenced in the `supertip` of the `Data Analysis` button after the Add-In was installed. Then I opened the file using the [Custom UI Editor Tool](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip) to view the XML. I saved an example file in [GitHub](https://github.com/StackOverflow-projects/52800440).

---

1. You can reference the action but not the controls of custom xlam e.g. `onAction="FUNCRES.XLAM!ShowATPDialog"`.
2. You can add the button to your custom group with the following XML. FYI, the Add-In must still be loaded for the button to work.

#### XML Code

```
<button 
    id="btnDataAnalysisTools"
    label="Data Analysis"
    imageMso="XmlMapProperties"
    onAction="FUNCRES.XLAM!ShowATPDialog"
    size="large"
    screentip="Data Analysis Tools"
    supertip="Tools for financial and scientific data analysis. Referenced from FUNCRES.XLAM"
/>
```

#### Example video

[image: video]

2a. The following options are available if you want to load an Add-In at runtime. [Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/accelerating_things/2010/09/16/loading-excel-add-ins-at-runtime/)

- Application.RegisterXLL

  - This is a method which can be called from VBA which loads an XLL at a specific location and registers the functions and commands contained in the XLL.
- AddIns.Add

  - This is a method which can be called from VBA which loads any type of add-in (XLL, XLA or XLAM). After loading the add-in, perform step 3 to open it.
- AddIn.Installed = true

  - Once you have a reference to a loaded add-in, set AddIn.Installed = true to cause the add-in to be opened.
  - Note that add-ins that are known when Excel is started with the /automation switch will already be marked as "Installed", but they are not opened. In this case, Set Installed = false before setting Installed = true

#### VBA Code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim success As Boolean
    Dim myAddIn As AddIn

    ' Load XLL
    success = Application.RegisterXLL("c:\myaddins\myxll.xll")

    ' Load and install new XLAM
    Set myAddIn = Application.AddIns.Add("c:\myaddins\myxlam.xlam")
    myAddIn.Installed = True

    ' Load known XLAM
    For Each myAddIn In AddIns
        If myAddIn.Name = "myknownaddin.xlam" Then
            myAddIn.Installed = False
            myAddIn.Installed = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

3. If your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define then you need to use the [JavaScript API for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office)